# Should a tag ever be an adjective?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Do you understand [hierachical](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierachical)?  How about [relational](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational)?

It sounds like unhelpful marketing speak.

**All our tags should be nouns. Any tags that are not nouns should be renamed as such.**

Do you agree?

Comment: Hope that edit helps. Additionally, I think that verbs or nouns are appropriate, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49455/should-we-keep-dependent-adjective-tags-such-as-multidimensional this has been brought up before as a network effect and has not been properly decided as one way or the other, but if Grace thinks they're not as useful, I agree with Grace. I say we can accept that non-actual-product adjectives are just superfluous.

Comment: +1 - I think adjective tags by themselves are incomplete.  What does `relational` mean on its own?

Answer (score 2):

Some [hierachical](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierachical) tags could replace it with [hierachical-query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierachical-query), but then similar compound tags would have to be created for those that do not fit this new tag.  If a question is just tagged [hierarchical](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchical) it probably needs another tag to provide context.  While it may not be able to stand alone as a tag it still helps limit the scope of the question and is therefore useful.

Comment: Wouldn't `hierarchy` make more sense as a tag though?

Comment: @JKN For some of the other questions it would, but for hierarchical queries it would not.  If you search Oracle documentation for example, Hierarchy doesn't return anything related to hierarchical queries (at least not in the first 10 pages of results), but Hierarchical does.  Compare http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?remark=quick_search&word=hierarchy and http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/search?remark=quick_search&word=hierarchical.